# Submitting a form on a different component

Tags: forms, angular

I have created a model based form on a component, however the submit button is placed on a different component.

right now when you press the button this function is triggerd:

```
@Input()
form: any;
...
if(this.form.valid)             
   this.saveDefinition();
```

however I want to "send a signal" back to my component with the form if the form is invalid. If the form is invalid it should highlight all the invalid fields (Like it would when you would submit the form on the same component).

I've searched for a while and I can't even find out if this is possible, if it is possible can you guys help me get on my way?

thanks

Comment: is your component with the form a child or a sibling of the component where the submit button is?

Comment: @deezg currently it's not, would this be required?

Comment: none is required, just trying to understand your components relation. so, when you say 'its not' what does that mean? its not a child or its not a sibling? please describe a bit their relation.

Comment: @deezg in my "main component" I have `<ng-content></ng-content>` and my other components are wrapped in this main component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use services, as follow:

form.service.ts file

```
@Injectable() 
export class FormService {
     onFormSubmitted = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

then register this service in the appModule providers appModue.ts file

```
providers: [
  ...
  FormService
  ...
]
```

firstComponent.ts file

```
@Component({
  ...
});
export class FirstComponent implements{

    constructor( public formService:FormService) {}

    onFormSubmit(formData:any) {
       this.formService.onFormSubmitted.emit(formData);
    }    
}
```

secondComponent.ts file

```
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit{

   constructor ( public formService:FormService ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.formService.onFormSubmitted.subscribe( (formData : any ) => {
         this.onFormSubmit(formData);
      })
   }

   onFormSubmit(formData : any) {
       // your logic for submitting the form
   }
}
```

the first and the second component have the same instance of FormService, so they have the same instance of the eventEmitter, the first component emitting the event when the form is submitting and the second component is listening to it.
its called cross-component communication using services.

Comment: I have implemented your code, but I can't figure this out `@Injectable() submitted ` gives me the error `unused expression, expected an assignment or function call`

Comment: `@Injectable() submitted` describes what?

Comment: I got rid of the line `@Injectable() submitted` and this solution works, thanks!

Comment: sorry, it should not be there :)

Comment: @RaedKhalaf I'm using ReactiveForms, my `Form`  is in 1st component and button is in 2nd component how to send `Form data` to button `function` ? I'm also using  `<ng-content>` where it is replaced by Form of 1st component