# Angular 2 emit event to application root component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, eventemitter

I want to emit an event to the component that  is the bootstrap of my application.
This component is the handler of a websocket connection, I need to send a message and this is why I have to emit this event.

In the bootstrap component I have only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` so I cannot realize how I can receive the event.

**Example**

*App.component.html*

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

*App.component.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

*App.module.ts*

```
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

App-routing.module.ts

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'display', component: MapDisplayComponent }
];
```

*Map-display.components.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-display',
  templateUrl: './map-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-display.component.scss']
})
export class MapDisplayComponent {
    @Output() sendMessage: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

So the problem is that the map-display component has to send the event to his parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a service.

1. Inject service into component and main component.
2. Add an emitter or an Observable to the service.
3. Add a function in the service to change the value of the Observable / emit a new value if your using an emitter.
4. Use the function in your component.
5. Subscribe to the emitter or the Observable in your main Component.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

you can use service to manage the communication between components.

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543347/submitting-a-form-on-a-different-component/45543755#45543755) question and the answer. 
don't forget to inject service into component and main component