# Animate a hamburger menu from Tailwind in Angular

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind UI in an Angular application and can open / close the hamburger menu with the following

```
<header>
  <div class="-mr-2 -my-2 md:hidden">
    <button type="button" (click)="toggleMobileMenu()"
      class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
      <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="absolute z-30 top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden" *ngIf="mobileMenuOpen">
    <div class="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 bg-white divide-y-2 divide-gray-50">

      <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
        <button (click)="toggleMobileMenu()" type="button"
          class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="py-6 px-5">
        <div class="grid gap-4">
          <a routerLink="/" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
            Home
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


toggleMobileMenu() {
  this.mobileMenuOpen = !this.mobileMenuOpen;
}
```

This is a really simple example.

How do I animate this?

The instructions are :

```
    Mobile menu, show/hide based on mobile menu state.

    Entering: "duration-200 ease-out"
      From: "opacity-0 scale-95"
      To: "opacity-100 scale-100"
    Leaving: "duration-100 ease-in"
      From: "opacity-100 scale-100"
      To: "opacity-0 scale-95"
```

and I don't know how to translate that to an angular animation

Comment: Did you checked this one ? https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers Should be as easy as settings classes on specific listeners during your transitions. (I'm not into Angular so cannot help further on)

Comment: I prefer to use the native angular animation, and have that integrated with Tailwind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is an approach I would follow.

1. **Ensure to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, ... ],
  ...
})
```

2. **Under your `@Component` decorator create `animations` array** as below

```typescript
@Component({
  ,,,,
  animations: [
    trigger("openClose", [
      // ...
      state(
        "open",
        style({
          opacity: 1,
          transform: "scale(1, 1)"
        })
      ),
      state(
        "closed",
        style({
          opacity: 0,
          transform: "scale(0.95, 0.95)"
        })
      ),
      transition("open => closed", [animate("100ms ease-in")]),
      transition("closed => open", [animate("200ms ease-out")])
    ])
  ]
})
```

In the animations array we have included below

- `trigger("openClose", [ ...])` which defines the name of our trigger. This will be used in the HTML template to bind to a dom element
- define 2 state using `state('stateName'` In our example above, the state names are `open` and `closed`
- Under state we define the styles using `style({ ... })`
- We finally define transition using `transition(...)`. This will define the timing and animation style

More on animations [Angular animations](https://angular.io/api/animations/animate#animate)

3. Define a getter for the state

```typescript
get openCloseTrigger() {
  return this.mobileMenuOpen ? "open" : "closed";
}
```

4. Bind state to getter to in the HTML

```html
<div [@openClose]="openCloseTrigger" ...> 
  <!-- Other stuff here -->
</div>
```

Everything should be ready and your menu should animate as desired

[See this demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p5yesh)

**Closing the browser on navigation**
We can leverage `NavigationEnd` event to achieve this functionality. When a user is on a specific page, then they will not navigate away from the page hence no `NavigationEnd`. The menu will remain open but when they navigate to another page, `NavigationEnd` event will be called and the menu will close

This is the approach

```typescript
constructor(private router: Router) {}
  navigationEnd$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    tap(() => (this.mobileMenuOpen = false))
  );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navigationEnd$.subscribe();
  }
```

[See this functionality on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avwhzp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Yes and I put the entire `trigger` block in a new `ts` file to make it reusable.

Comment: Below is an example of extracted trigger in a new file based on @Pieterjan comment above https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-99gnub

Comment: Thank you, this is great - how do I close the menu if the user clicks on an item in it?  Ie, if they click on home they route to there but the menu stays open.  @OwenKelvin

Comment: Simply set `this.mobileMenuOpen = false;`

Comment: Additionally to @Pieterjan suggestion, we can also add `NavigationEnd` event to watch when user navigates away from the page. When this happens, then we call `this.mobileMenuOpen = false`.  See updated solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that uses only tailwind classes for animation. Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tailwind-transition-stackoverflow-662575661160236?file=src/app/app.component.html)

And here is a brief explanation.

Initially for the mobile menu `div` we set the tailwind classes which keeps the `div` in a hidden state. and to do so we have used.

`scale-95` , `opacity-0` and we have also used `pointer-events-none` to avoid interactions in hidden state.

and when the menu is active we add the following classes.

`scale-100`, `opacity-100` and `pointer-events-auto`.

and to animate these properties we have used the `transition` class on the `div` and the  `duration-200` class for the transition duration.

```
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <header>
        <div class="-mr-2 -my-2 md:hidden">
            <button type="button" (click)="toggleMobileMenu()"
          class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        </div>
<!-- here we have added transition transform scale-95 opacity-0 duration-200 pointer-events-none -->
        <div class="absolute z-30 top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform scale-95 opacity-0 duration-200 pointer-events-none md:hidden"
            [ngClass]="{'scale-100 pointer-events-auto opacity-100': mobileMenuOpen}">
<!-- then toggle classes scale-100 opacity-100 and pointer-events-auto -->
            <div class="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 bg-white divide-y-2 divide-gray-50">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <button (click)="toggleMobileMenu()" type="button"
              class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
              </svg>
            </button>
                </div>
                <div class="py-6 px-5">
                    <div class="grid gap-4">
                        <a routerLink="/" (click)="toggleMobileMenu()" class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-700">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

So, just by using the right tailwind classes, you can achieve the animation effect.

Answer (score 0):

This thread really helped point me in the right direction. Using Angular 14 & [TailwindUI](https://tailwindui.com/) Here is what ended up working for me.

I needed to render a [notification](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/overlays/notifications) to display the response from an http request. I have created a `NotificationService` that I subscribe to that handles the show (emit). I found [this SO thread(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128377/angular-2-emit-event-to-application-root-component) to be super helpful accomplishing that.

```
// app.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [],
    animations: [
        trigger('renderNotification', [
            transition(':enter', [
                style({
                    transform: 'translateY(0.5rem)',
                    opacity: 0,
                }),
                animate(
                    '150ms 0ms ease-out',
                    style({
                        transform: 'translateY(0)',
                        opacity: 1,
                    })
                ),
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                style({
                    transform: 'translateY(0)',
                    opacity: 1,
                }),
                animate(
                    '100ms 0ms ease-in',
                    style({
                        transform: 'translateX(0.5rem)',
                        opacity: 0,
                    })
                ),
            ]),
        ]),
    ],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    showNotification: boolean = false;
    ...
}
```

```
<!-- app.component.html -->

<div class="flex h-full">
    <div
        aria-live="assertive"
        class="pointer-events-none fixed inset-0 z-50 flex items-end px-4 py-6 sm:items-start sm:p-6"
    >
        <div class="flex w-full flex-col items-center space-y-4 sm:items-end">
            <app-notifications
                class=""
                [@renderNotification]="notification.show"
                *ngIf="showNotification"
                [type]="notification.type"
                [title]="notification.title"
                [body]="notification.body"
                (closeNotificationEvent)="closeNotification()"
            ></app-notifications>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

    <div class="flex min-w-0 flex-1 flex-col overflow-hidden">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone else!